# Facebook messenger webhook not receiving updates

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api

I can't get messages via `messenger webhook`. It was working fine earlier.

In `webhook` section, i just write the `input Json` to a `text file`.

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents('php://input');
file_put_contents('test.txt',$jsondata);
```

The only change i made was upgrading server from PHP5 to PHP7.

When i test from Facebook, it says that sample update was successfully sent to my server.

And it works fine when i input `Json` via `Curl`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/psgqY.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxqTr.jpg

Comment: _“In webhook section i just write the input json to a text file”_ - maybe that’s part of the problem here, because that will only ever show you what data the _last_ request contained. At least make it _append_ to the file, instead of overwriting it each time. Might make sense to log the current timestamp as well, so that you can compare with your access log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed When i renewed SSL certificate, forgot to add SSL bundle file